# How to pass parameters to a cypher using IN operator?

Tags: java, cypher, neo4j

We are using Neo4j 2.0 RC1 embedded in our java server. We parametrize the variables in our cyphers. One of our cyphers uses IN clause e.g.

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name IN ["Peter", "Tobias"] RETURN a
```

So i tried something like this:

```
String cypher = "MATCH (a) WHERE a.name IN {names} RETURN a";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
//add some names to the names list
params.put("names", names);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(cypher, params);
```

Its obviously not working, how do i parametrize IN operator ?

Comment: I copied your code snippet and it works for me. What happens when you run it?

Comment: i got a bug elsewhere which caused the error. things work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neo4j rocks !!

Things work as expected / desired. I got a bug elsewhere in the code otherwise the following snippet works just fine:

```
String cypher = "MATCH (a) WHERE a.name IN {names} RETURN a";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
//add some names to the names list
params.put("names", names);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(cypher, params);
```